# Where is mininet installed to?

Tags: python, directory, mininet

I want to change `link.py` of mininet. I use Ubuntu 14.04 and the current version of the git repository of mininet. When I change the files in the mininet directory this does not take effect.

It seems that there is a cached version somewhere but I cannot find it.

Even if I delete the `mininet` folder under my user home directory I can still execute it. So there must be a "compiled" version somewhere.

Would be great if someone could help :)

Comment: How do you execute it after folder deletion?

Comment: I simply run my python script that creates the topology using the mininet classes. The are imported via "from mininet.* import *"

Comment: Are you sure mininet wasn't installed by OS package manager? What does `sudo aptitude search mininet` output?

Comment: I found the solution. see my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. I had to delete the file

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mininet-2.2.1d2-py2.7.egg
```

and then re-run the install.sh from the mininet git repository (after I did my changes)

```
install.sh -n
```

the n-flag avoids re-installing other packages than mininet.

Then the .egg was created again and my changes took effect. nice :)

EDIT:
the install.sh -n option calls

```
sudo make install
```

which calls

```
python setup.py install
```

which uses

```
setuptools.setup
```

of python to compile the source to an .egg file.

I hope this helps anyone who will encounter the same problems as me...